# How do I use a for loop in JavaScript to add all positive integers to 'sum'?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var n = 25;
```

1. Declare a new variable named "sum" initialized to 0. Be sure to use the "var" keyword.
2. Use a for loop to add every positive integer less than n to sum.
3. Come up with a solution that works for all values of n.

Above are the conditions of the code to be written. Below is what I have written. However, I keep getting an error stating "the sum of all integers less than 2 is 1". Is there something wrong with my code, or am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

```
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    sum += i;
  } else {
    sum = sum;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only adding the even integers, not all integers. Also, you should use `i < n`, not `i <= n`.

Comment: why are you doing a `mod` there's no such specification like that in your question

Comment: What is the point of `sum = sum`? Are you worried that the variable will forget what it holds if you don't remind it?

Comment: Thank you, the previous exercise had me dealing with only even numbers. I must still be in that mindset.

Comment: You don't need to include `0` in your `for` loop.  You would be fine with `for (i = 1; i < n; i++)`

Comment: In fact, according to the specification, you shouldn't include `0`, since it's not a positive integer. But when adding, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the conditions in the for loop. Seems those are for conditions where you want even/odd numbers. And you should iterate over indexes `1` to `n-1`, i.e., up to but not including `n`, or `i < n`. Also notice you were asked to sum the positive numbers only. Technically you shouldn't sum `0` in the start, mean you should start at `i = 1`. However, mathematically speaking, this last thing doesn't actually change the result.

```
var n = 25;
var sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

An alternative is also:

```
var n = 25;
sum = Array.from(new Array(n), (x, i) => i).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

However, IMO it's too "fancy" and not as readable, and technically sums with zero in the start.

Answer (score 0):

it is just as simple as this, remember to use var in the for loop.

```
    var n = 25;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
```